# How to do a basic authentication in a functional view in Django?

Tags: python, django, basic-authentication

I want to do a `basic authentication` on a `functional view`. The view is expecting a `POST` request from a client script. So as soon as the client is authenticated, it will `POST` some new data to the view. 
Also I would like to know about how the `session` is maintained. Will the user have to be authenticated again if it makes a new request after a while? If not, then what is the procedure to force an authentication next time it wants to POST something?

Is there a decorator `@has_basicauth` in the decorators module? If yes how can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discoverd there is a pretty simple way.

```
from decorators import has_basicauth

@has_basicauth['RestricedRealm']
def some_view(request)
...
...
```

Thus when someone tries to reach the URL via a browser, the browser automatically prompts for the Username and the Password.